# Microsoft Graph error InvalidAuthenticationToken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, adal.js

When I trying to retrieve some data from MS Graph I get the following error:

```
{error: {code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken", message: "Access token validation failure.",…}}
error:{code: "InvalidAuthenticationToken", message: "Access token validation failure.",…}
code:"InvalidAuthenticationToken"
innerError:{request-id: " xxx ", date: "2016-11-28T10:25:52"}
date : "2016-11-28T10:25:52"
request-id: " xxx "
message : "Access token validation failure."
```

The application is a SharePoint Add-In which should read some user and group information from Office 365.

I use the follwoing code to retrieve the data:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
            }
        }).done(function (response) {

            console.log(response);

            //alert(response);

        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('Error occurred.');
        });
```

For authenication I use adal.js. After login() I get the id_token. When the request is made the token is passed to the function.

Does anyone has the same issue and could help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used the wrong endpoint in the `aquireToken` request. So the code above is correct. Many thanks to Fei Xue for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To call the Microsoft Graph REST, we need to provide the **access token**. The **id_token** is used by client to verify the sign-in user.

To acquire the deligate access token for the Microsoft Graph REST, we need to make two request. The first request is get the **Authorization Code** from authorization endpoint. The second request is that exchange the token using the code get from the first request. About the detail request, you can refer the link below:

[Microsoft Graph app authentication using Azure AD](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization)